# React Native/Expo + Next.js app crashes in Expo app (Can't find variable: React, in withExpoRoot.js)

Tags: react-native, expo, next.js

I have a React Native/Expo + Next.js app (built with `npx create-next-app -e with-expo`)

Full code: https://github.com/tomsoderlund/reactnative-nextjs-template

It runs fine as a web app (both in Next.js and in Expo Web) but crashed when running on the Expo app on iPhone:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: React

This error is located at:
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:26)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:40)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:101)
    in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

[image: Expo error]

How can I make it run?

Comment: Have you tried adding `import React from 'react'` at the top of your `index.js` page?

Comment: @juliomalves OMG it was that simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import React at the top of your `index.js` page for it to get picked up when running your app in Expo.

```js
import React from 'react'
```